# check 2 array of object if the value same or different

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have 2 data array the first array is old data (history before the data change) , and the new data is the current data will showing at grid. first of all i already create function with javascript like this. its gonna compare value the new data and the old data if the `ID` have same value, if the new value not same as old i add `<p class="red"></p>` and if the old value is null or blank but the new value is not i add `<p class="grey"></p>`, and nothing happen if the value not change or same . at this example i only have 3 key of object `ID` as main, and `Name` and `Address`. how to make this function more effective or flexible if i have so many key of object to be compare

```js
// as a old data
var old_data = [
{"ID":4,"Name":"Sad","Address":null},
{"ID":5,"Name":"Happy","Address":"Address 2"}
]

//as a new data
var new_data = [
{"ID":4,"Name":"Very Sad","Address":"Address 1"},
{"ID":5,"Name":"Happy","Address":"Address 2 New"},
{"ID":6,"Name":"Well","Address":"Address 3"}
]

var showing = [];
var temp_old = [];
var temp_new = [];

for(var i=0;i<new_data.length;i++){ //foreach the main array
    
    temp_old = [];
    temp_new = [];
    
    if(old_data.some(item => item.ID === new_data[i].ID)){
        //showing.push(new_data[i]); //push to array will be show
        temp_old = old_data.filter(item => item.ID === new_data[i].ID);
        temp_new.push(new_data[i]);

        if(new_data[i].Name!=temp_old[0].Name){ // check if value Name at new data data change or not
            if(temp_old[0].Name!=null && temp_old[0].Name!=""){
                    temp_new[0].Name = '<p class="red">'+new_data[i].Name+'</p>'; //if change add class red
                }else{
                    temp_new[0].Name = '<p class="grey">'+new_data[i].Name+'</p>'; //if change but the old data data null or blank add class grey
            }
        }

        if(new_data[i].Address!=temp_old[0].Address){ // check if value Address at new data data change or not
            if(temp_old[0].Address!=null && temp_old[0].Address!=""){
                    temp_new[0].Address = '<p class="red">'+new_data[i].Address+'</p>'; //if change add class red
                }else{
                    temp_new[0].Address = '<p class="grey">'+new_data[i].Address+'</p>'; //if change but the old data data null or blank add class grey
            }
        }

        showing.push(temp_new[0]);
    }else{
        showing.push(new_data[i]); //push to array will be show
  
    }
}


console.log(showing);
```

Comment: You can keep obj comparison(deep compare) in a different function, that will return status, based on return status add use the logic to apply desired class. This way you can isolate the comparison of objects from current function.

Comment: Is it the shape of Old data and new data must be the same? What if the Old have 5keys and new data only have 3 keys?

Comment: you are comparing to index  be carfull when one ID is missing can create problem, i will suggest you see [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function of Array in javascript for easy implementation

Comment: @ikhvjs they key of old data and new data will be gonna be same , only the value will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()`.

```js
// as a old_data
var oldData = [{ ID: 4, Name: "Sad", Address: null, Tel: "3948238852" }];

//as a new data
var newData = [
  { ID: 4, Name: "Very Sad", Address: "Address 1", Tel: "3948238852" },
  { ID: 5, Name: "Happy", Address: "Address 2", Tel: "3948238852" },
  { ID: 6, Name: "Well", Address: "Address 3", Tel: "3948238852" },
];

const output = newData.map(n => {
  const matchOldData = oldData.find(o => o.ID === n.ID);
  if (matchOldData) {
    const newDataKeys = Object.keys(n).filter(k => k != "ID");
    return newDataKeys.reduce(
      (acc, key) => {
        if (
          matchOldData[key] === "" ||
          matchOldData[key] === null ||
          matchOldData[key] === undefined
        ) {
          acc[key] = `<p class="grey">${n[key]}</p>`;
        } else if (matchOldData[key] !== n[key]) {
          acc[key] = `<p class="red">${n[key]}</p>`;
        } else {
          acc[key] = n[key];
        }
        return acc;
      },
      { ID: n.ID }
    );
  } else {
    return n;
  }
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the `temp_data` inside the nested for loop. And then, try change the `showing.push(temp_data[0])` to `showing.push[temp_data]` to see if all the value is being push.